# gdal merge with all rgba channels

Tags: gdal, merge

I successfully merged my imagery data, but the problem is that "merge" function treated an alpha as a transparency instead of an additional channel which has to be merged.

How to merge all rgba properly?

Unfortunately there is no -extend rgba function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gdal_merge is not really built for your current usage.

Instead I'd suggest that you use [gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) potentially followed by [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) if the vrt-format is not suitable for your use.

A gdalbuildvrt example for your usage would be:

```
gdalbuildvrt MergedImage.vrt InputImageA.tif InputImageB.tif
```

You'll note that the output MergedImage.vrt is merely a 'virtual' file, which simply references your input images. If you need to move the file and do further stuff with it, you can then use gdal_translate to convert the file into a 4-band tif-file again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the instructions!  This is what finally worked in my case:  First step:  raster>misce...> merge:
`gdalbuildvrt MergedImage.vrt E:\work\...\m_4011726_ne_11_1_20150715_20150923.jp2 E:\work\...\m_4011726_nw_11_1_20150715_20150923.jp2 E:\work\...\m_4011726_se_11_1_20150715_20150923.jp2 E:\...\m_4011726_sw_11_1_20150715_20150923.jp2`     Second: raster>misce...> merge:
`gdal_translate -of JP2OpenJPEG MergedImage.vrt E:/aaa.jp2`   In photoshop you need to click: Image>mode>multichannel, image>mode>rgb.  So you will have 8bit rgba image you can save as you want!

Comment: @kurt_hectic - if it solved your problems, please mark the my answer as 'accepted'.